# Insertion sort generic way in Ada

Tags: ada, generic-programming, insertion-sort

.ads content:

```
generic

   type Item is private;
   type Index is (<>) ;
   type Table_Array is array (Index range <>) of Item;

    with function "<" (A, B: Item) return Boolean is <>  ;


   procedure TableSort ( T : in out Table_Array ) ;
```

So here's my insertion sort code:

```
 procedure TableSort ( T: in out Table_Array) is
   x : Item ;
   j: Index;
   begin

   for I in T'Range loop

      if T(Index'Succ(I)) < T(I)   then

         x := T(I) ;
         T(I) := T(Index'Succ(I));
         j := Index'Pred(Index'Pred(I));



         while  j <= T'First and x < T(Index'succ(j)) loop
            T(j) := T(Index'Succ(j)) ;
            j := Index'Pred(j);

         end loop ;
         T(Index'Pred(I)) := x ;

      end if ;

   end loop;

 end TableSort ;
```

The problem is with `j := Index'Pred(Index'Pred(I));`.
It does not accept it, and I do not know how to make it work. My buddy has it done, and he split it to pieces. Any other idea?

Comment: What do you expect `Index'Pred(Index'Pred(I))` to do?

Comment: This is incomplete. You expect us to guess what the missing bits are, which could well be wasting your time as well as ours. We have no idea what "It does not accept it" means; why not just quote the output? What does "split it to pieces" mean? That said, you need to think about the end values of `T’Range`. If `Index` is just an `Integer`, then `T(Index’Succ(I))` is going to give you a `Constraint_Error` (index check failed) at the end of the range. If `Index` is constrained (e.g. `range 1 .. 100`) you’re likely to get CE when you say `Index'Pred(Index'Pred(I))` at the start of the range.

Comment: Yes you are right, I added the specification of tablesort. I expect it to return the element before the previous element. Error : "raised CONSTRAINT_ERROR : tablesort.adb:18 overflow check failed "

Comment: And what you get is what happens when there is no *element before the previous element*. You need to handle that case properly to eliminate the error.

Comment: Hard to see how you could get "overflow check failed" on `j := Index'Pred(j);`. What is your actual type `Index`?